# Zookeeper systemctl service stops with status code 14

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am following a course on confluent kafka. I have 3 servers where I have installed community edition 2.13:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.confluent.io/deb/5.2 stable main"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk confluent-community-2.13
```

I have set the hosts on the server:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
  
172.31.27.164 zoo1
172.31.29.209 zoo2
172.31.25.79 zoo3
```

I have set up the zookeeper properties:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=24
```

Set the `myid` in `/var/lib/zookeeper/myid` to 1, 2 and 3 for each server respectively.

I have also changed some properties in the kafka/server.properties files:

```
broker.id=1
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://zoo1:9092
zookeeper.connect=zoo1:2181
```

Then I have tried to run zookeeper and kafka:

```
sudo systemctl start confluent-zookeeper
sudo systemctl enable confluent-zookeeper
sudo systemctl start confluent-kafka
sudo systemctl enable confluent-kafka
```

But, when I check the status with `sudo systemctl status confluent*` then I get an error:

```
confluent-zookeeper.service - Apache Kafka - ZooKeeper

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/confluent-zookeeper.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-03-26 21:43:57 UTC; 20s ago

Docs: http://docs.confluent.io/

Process: 28246 ExecStart=/usr/bin/zookeeper-server-start /etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties (code=exited, status=14)

Main PID: 28246 (code=exited, status=14)
```

What is wrong here, how can I fix this?

Comment: Look at the service logs (`journalctl -u confluent-zookeeper`) not Systemctl status

Comment: Also, I highly recommend using Java 11 and a Confluent version newer than 5.2